# Mercator Projection.

Tags: differential-geometry

I am trying to derive the metrics for the  Mercator Projection using standard spherical coordinates $f(\phi, \theta) = (\cos\phi \cos\theta, \sin\phi \cos\theta, \sin\theta)  $. For simplicity, I consider the radius of the Earth is equal to 1. Then I am using a quadratic differential of the first fundamental form: $ds^2=Edu^2+2FDuDv+Gdv^2$; where $E, F, G$ are elements of the matrix representation of the first fundamental form of $f$, that is $E = \cos^2\theta; F =0$, and  $G=1$. So the metrics of the sphere is $ds^2=\cos^2\theta d\phi^2+d\theta^2$.
I am looking for projections: functions $x=x(\phi,\theta); y=y(\phi,\theta)$.
Next, I let loxodrome be a function $\phi=\phi(\theta)$ then the velocity vector will be $v=(\phi',1)$. And meridian has a condition $\phi = const$, then as a parameter, I choose $\theta$, which gives me a velocity vector $m =(0,1)$.
Then the loxodrome should make a constant angle $\psi$ with the meridian. So I can write:

$ \cos\psi =\frac{\lt v,m \gt}{\Vert v \Vert \Vert m \Vert} = \frac{1}{ \sqrt{ \cos^2\theta \phi'^2 +1}  } $.
I understand the last expression. But can someone explain to me the length of the velocity vector $v$? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The length of the velocity vector $v=<\phi',1> =<d\phi/dt, d\theta/dt>$  is $ds/dt$. Using the metric $ds^2=\cos^2\theta d\phi ^2 + d\theta^2$, this becomes  $(ds/dt)^2=  \cos^2\theta (\phi')^2+ 1^2$.

Comment: Just so you know, `\langle u,v \rangle` (giving $\langle u,v\rangle$) gives a better typesetting than `<u,v>` (which gives $<u,v>$).

Comment: Thank you, @MathWonk